# css.file in sub folder is not linked correctly

Tags: php, html, css

I restructured my project and experience problems when it comes to the link of my .css-file

- I am using xampp/Apache
- The .htaccess file is in ".../htdocs/project" including "RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f"
- My Head partial is in ".../htdocs/project/views/partials/head.part.view.php" and includes the link element to the .css-file
- the head partial is included in each view
- my index.php is in ".../htdocs/project/public/index.php" (xampp needs the htdocs folder)

1. When my style.css is located directly inside ".../htdocs/project/style.css" The link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='../style.css'>
```

inside my head section works well.
2. When I move my style.css to ".../htdocs/project/css/style.css" obviously above link breaks but even

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='../css/style.css'>
```

does not work.
I don't understand why.

Thanks!

This is even more confusing as when I include to my head partial (directly below the css-link)
`<?php include '../css/test.php'; ?>`
and insert an echo inside test.php inside the same folder as the css-file... it (edit:only the echo - not the css) works... can someone help me?

I also tried complete paths and it does not work as soon as the css-file is inside the css folder.

If you think that it has something to do with the .htaccess, I can post the content there but for me this seems not to have any effect... on the other hand I am absolutely confused about this.

edit:
It seems to me to get closer to the problem. When I inspect in the browser I can see that the page seems to refer to a style.css but it is an old version that is obviously not there on the webserver but the browser seems to find it.
I have tried to delete all temp internet files, cookies but it seems to still find the not existing style.css file... any idea?

edit: I now figured out, that it indeed is caused by the .htaccess file. I thought I understand the function within but it seems I don't really. As this is another topic I will first of all try to find out what exactly my commands inside the.htaccess files does and if there re still problems I will open a new thread for solutions for .htaccess-configurations. Thanks for all ideas and help!

Comment: What do you mean by "breaks"? How is this problem related to PHP?

Answer (score -1):

Use : `href='../../css/style.css'`